# Spring Boot jsp files cannot be found

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm developing simple Spring Boot MVC application. Previously I had everything working with just Spring + Hibernate (that is there was servlet.xml etc.) and I'm trying to rebuild project to use Spring Boot. Althought I have read many answers on SO I still can't fix Spring Boot not finding my .jsp files - it displays whitelabel error page.
Many answers on SO are about including `tomcat-embed-jasper` and `jstl` in `pom.xml` but I already have it. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 17 Ultimate, Tomcat 8.5.13, latest versions of Spring and Spring Boot.

Project structure:
[image]

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>spring-invoice</artifactId>
<groupId>spring-invoice</groupId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.9.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.41</mysql.connector.version>
    <hibernatevalidator.version>5.4.1.Final</hibernatevalidator.version>
    <start-class>com.invoices.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernatevalidator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- C3PO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet + JSP + JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

    <finalName>spring-invoice</finalName>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <!-- The Compiler Plugin is used to compile the sources of project -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Builds a Web Application Archive (WAR) file from the project output and its dependencies. -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>

</project>
```

`application.properties` file

```
# Database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fakturowanie
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

entitymanager.packagesToScan=com.invoices
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

One of my jsp files

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html lang="pl-PL">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Zarządzaj kontrahentami</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>Zarządzaj kontrahentami</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <!-- put new button: Add Customer -->
            <input type="button" value="Dodaj nowego kontrahenta"
                   onclick="window.location.href='addCustomer'; return false;"
                   class="add-button"/>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Alias</th>
                    <th>Nazwisko</th>
                    <th>Imię</th>
                    <th>Nazwa firmy</th>
                    <th>NIP/PESEL</th>
                    <th>Ulica i nr mieszkania</th>
                    <th>Kod pocztowy</th>
                    <th>Miejscowość</th>
                    <th>Sposób zapłaty</th>
                    <th>Uwzględnij numer faktury</th>
                </tr>

                <c:forEach var="tempCustomer" items="${allCustomers}">

                    <c:url var="updateLink" value="/customers/updateCustomer">
                        <c:param name="customerID" value="${tempCustomer.id}"/>
                    </c:url>

                    <c:url var="deleteLink" value="/customers/deleteCustomer">
                        <c:param name="customerID" value="${tempCustomer.id}"/>
                    </c:url>

                    <tr>
                        <td>${tempCustomer.alias}</td>
                        <td>${tempCustomer.lastName}</td>
                        <td>${tempCustomer.firstName}</td>
                        <td>${tempCustomer.companyName}</td>
                        <td>${tempCustomer.taxIdentifier}</td>
                        <td>${tempCustomer.postalCode}</td>
                        <td>${tempCustomer.city}</td>
                        <td>${tempCustomer.paymentMethod}</td>
                        <td>${tempCustomer.includeInCount}</td>

                        <td>
                            <!-- display the update and delete link -->
                            <a href="${updateLink}">Edytuj</a>
                            |
                            <a href="${deleteLink}" onclick="if (!(confirm(
                                'Czy na pewno usunąć tego kontrahenta?'))) return false">Usuń</a>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </c:forEach>

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And controller of it

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomersController implements IUtilities<Customer>
{
    @Autowired
    private ICustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @GetMapping("/manageCustomers")
    public String manageCustomers(Model model)
    {
        List<Customer> allCustomers = convertIterableToCollection(customerDAO.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("allCustomers", allCustomers);
        return "manage-customers";
    }

    @GetMapping("/addCustomer")
    public String showFormForAdd(Model model)
    {
        // create model attribute to bind form data
        Customer theCustomer = new Customer();

        model.addAttribute("customerToEdit", theCustomer);

        return "customer-form";
    }

    @GetMapping("/updateCustomer")
    public String showFormForUpdate(@RequestParam("customerID") int customerId, Model model)
    {
        // get the customer from service
        Customer theCustomer = customerDAO.findOne(customerId);
        model.addAttribute("customerToEdit", theCustomer);

        //redirect to update form
        return "customer-form";
    }

    @GetMapping("/deleteCustomer")
    public String deleteCustomer(@RequestParam("customerID") int customerId)
    {
        //delete the customer
        customerDAO.delete(customerId);

        return "redirect:/customers/manageCustomers";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveCustomer")
    public String saveCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customerToEdit") Customer customer) {
        //save the customer using our service
        customerDAO.save(customer);

        return "redirect:/customers/manageCustomers";
    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> convertIterableToCollection(Iterable<Customer> iterable) {
        List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        iterable.forEach(list::add);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you add bean for viewResolver

Comment: I guess I have nothing like viewResolver in my project, I have neither xml files nor any config class

Comment: See my answer, your basic issue is not using the expected maven project layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot but your pom is riddled with conflicting dependencies. For starters cleanup your `pom.xml`. Also in your pom you should take into account what is being done in the [JSP Samples pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) (Which means at least make the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` `provided` instead of the default `compile` scope.

Finally you don't need the `maven-compile` and `maven-war` plugins as those are already inherited from the parent.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>spring-invoice</artifactId>
<groupId>spring-invoice</groupId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.9.Final</hibernate.version>
    <start-class>com.invoices.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- C3PO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet + JSP + JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

    <finalName>spring-invoice</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>

</build>

</project>
```

Also take into account [the limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations)  there are when using Spring Boot with JSPs.

However the actual problem is your project structure, you are using Maven with should have a `src/main/java` directory for your java sources and all your web related things should be in `src/main/webapp` instead of `web`, further non java related resources should be in `src/main/resources`. Due to not having this default structure files aren't going to be copied to the correct location (actually they will be ignored).

Comment: I inherited `pom.xml` from previous version of the project - I'll try to clean it up and see if it's working

Comment: See my modified answer (the actual problem is your project structure). Non the less cleaning up your pom will prevent further issues (and maintenance).

Comment: That's what I thought to be honest but, still, it's what IntelliJ's giving me when I'm creating a new project. Does that mean that I have to manually rebuild project structure every single time when working with Spring Boot and Maven?

Comment: You should create a maven project in Intellij not a plain (or web) project.

Comment: Ok, got it. I manually added `pom.xml` since previous version was based on manually imported jars. Give me some time and I'll try to include all advice in my project.

Comment: I cleaned up `pom.xml` and changed project structure but ended `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext`

Comment: @Colonder if you dont have many JSP files I would point you to migrate your JSP files to thymeleaf, its the internal spring templates, with internal attributes to replace all JSTL tags, and the migration would be quite fast. ONly if you dont have massive number of JSP files

Comment: When do you get that exception (I expect when running it in IntelliJ?).